# Telling the python interpreter to take the current path for resolving relative directories

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a very ordinary source code repository, like the following structure:

```
aProject
|-----> __init__.py
|-----> src
|       |-----> __init__.py
|       |-----> file1.py
|       |-----> file2.py
|
|-----> test
        |-----> __init__.py
        |-----> test_file1.py
        |-----> augmentationFile.py
```

Unique to my case, test_file1.py uses augmentationFile.py which references src directory and the `from src import *` statement inside augmentationFile.py succeeds finding the modules.

I can run unittest module from the main aProject directory and the sys.path inside augmentationFile.py shows "" as its first argument. This enables python to find relative src directories.

However, when I run from the aProject directory alike, this time using `python test/augmentationFile.py`, python sets sys.path[0] to test folder and cannot resolve the `from src import *` statement and complains.

How do I tell the python interpreter (I may be mistaken to find an appropriate flag perusing the [python 3 document on cmdline](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html)) to infer directories correctly? One option that comes to my mind is changing the augmentationFile.py's import statement to an if statement checking sys.path and decides whether to import from "..src" or "src". Being have to changing the source code like this in every similar situation scares me.
Therefore, I am asking if and how its possible to tell the interpreter, to resolve relative paths considering the current working directory?
Thank you,

Comment: **This is what i use to get the working directory & continue the remaining operations**


    import os
    path = os.getcwd()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have deliberately run the file as a module it resolved: `python -m test.augmentationFile`. The problem was about the error location of the src statement, it was residing down inside the code, wasn't an ordinary import statement.